# Which kernel option for "Intel 8 Series Chipset Family Thermal Management Controller"

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-modules

My new machine works fine, but *lshw* shows the following unclaimed device:

```
    *-generic UNCLAIMED
         description: Signal processing controller
         product: 8 Series Chipset Family Thermal Management Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1f.6
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
         version: 05
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm msi cap_list
         configuration: latency=0
         resources: memory:f7330000-f7330fff
```

The PCI ID of the device, according to *lspci* is **8086:8c24**.

I could not find any details about it. Which kernel config option do I need to enable for it? In case it matters, I'm using [this mainboard](http://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/Xeon/C220/X10SLL-F.cfm), which is using the Intel C222 chipset.

Comment: What makes you think you *need* a driver for it?  These kinds of motherboard devies often don't.

Comment: I know this question is antique, but did you find any solution? My laptop (Dell M3800) overheates because of that.

Comment: Maybe module named `coretemp` which is kernel `.config` option `CONFIG_SENSORS_CORETEMP`. I needed it to have the ability to see the temperatures for i7-8700k CPU via `sensors` command (from `lm_sensors` package). However, I'm pretty sure that most Linux distributions already have that (as a module, at least), so unless you customized your kernel `.config` yourself(and accidentally disabled it?), this is probably not the config option that you are looking for.